# Access properties of the global JS context without DOM

Tags: javascript, dom, global-variables

I'd like to access all the attributes of the global JS scope in my application.

There is no DOM, so I **can't** use the following:

```
for (var attr in window) {
  // attr is in the global scope
}
```

Is there a way to get a reference to the global JS scope?

Comment: What's your environment if there's no DOM? Node?

Comment: self and this usually work.

Comment: Are you effectively asking if you can get access to the environment record  of a given execution context? If so, the answer is pretty much "no".

Comment: @CrazyTrain—[ECMA-262 §10.4.1.1](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.4.1.1) specifies that *this* in a global execution context references the global object. It also specifies that when not in strict mode, *this* defaults to the global object when not set to some other object by the call. So while environments aren't required (and don't) provide access to *any* execution context/variable object/activation object/whatever, they *are* required to provide access to the global object (which is effectively the global variable object).

Comment: @RobG: My comment was that the `window` property was a host-provided property and is not required.

Comment: @elclanrs Any JS interpreter. In my case: JavascriptCore for iOS & Rhino for Android.

Comment: @CrazyTrain—ok, yes, *window* is for browsers (and maybe other host environments with a UI).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In non–strict mode you can get a reference to the global object using *this*:

```
var globalObj = (function(){return this}());
```

as if you don't set *this* in the call, it defaults to the global object. That will work in any execution context (but not in strict mode). Simpler to just create a global variable that references the global object:

```
var global = this;
```

or pass it to an IIFE:

```
(function (global) {
  // In here, global === global object
  ...
}(this))
```

Whatever suits.

Comment: +1 I wondered if ECMAScript required `this` to reference the global object within the global execution context, and it seems that it does. http://es5.github.io/#x10.4.1.1